# append variable to string html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

lets say i have this variable:

```
var personalizedHTML = '<html>' +
    '<head>' +
        '<title>TODO supply a title</title>' +
        '<meta charset="UTF-8">' +
        '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">' +
        '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>' +
        '<script src="js/function.js" type="text/javascript"></script>' +
    '</head>' +
    '<body>' +
        '<form>' +
        '</form>' +
    '</body>' +
'</html>';
```

and I want to append this one between the form tags

```
var formGroupFirstName = '<div class="form-group">' +
            '<label for="inputFirstname" class="control-label">' + desiredLanguageFirstName +
            '<span class="required">*</span></label>' +
            '<input type="text" aria-required="true" required="" placeholder="" id="inputFirstname"' +
            'class="form-control input-lg" name="first_name"/></div>';
```

Is there a way to do it using jquery?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Select the `form` element and `append` the `formGroupFirstName` html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('form').append(formGroupFirstName);
```

Try this, as @Explosion Pills mentioned.

Comment: can you use jquery selectors on a string variable?

I tried it but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `find` and then append the `form` element with `innerHTML` property! Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1oaxmrqp/1

```
var formele=el.html(personalizedHTML).find('form').get();
formele[0].innerHTML=formGroupFirstName;
```